# How to keep track of each account's ETH balance when parsing all historical transactions

Tags: transactions, blocks, internal-transactions

I have downloaded the contents of each historical Ethereum block (starting with block 0) by calling eth_getBlockByNumber for every single block.

I want to write a script that iterates over each transaction in each block, in chronological order, and updates an internal data structure which maps each address to its ETH balance.

If I were to do this with any ERC20 token, I would simply process each Transfer log and update accordingly. However, there are no logs for ETH transfers, so I am not sure how to do this. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

This task is relatively complex if you want to scrape and index the chain from scratch.

You can achieve this by tracing each transaction using `trace_transaction`

Let's take this example using web3.py:

> Note that you need to enable the tracing namespace on the Erigon client. You can do it with [Chainstack following the docs here](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-trace_transaction#enable-the-erigon-client-on-your-elastic-ethereum-node), but other providers might also have the option.

```py
from web3 import Web3
import json

# Configuration
NODE_URL = "RPC_URL_WITH_TRACES_ENABLED"  # Replace with your Ethereum node URL

TX_HASHES = [
    "0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461",
    "0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028",
    "0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8",
    "0x8c7dd9f6c3aec7e3e49cbf95eb602ff356929de72179515b5cc0270b64d83a32",
    "0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e",
    "0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c",
    "0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56",
    "0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13",
    "0x004903819dbb2ce40e3eaf6bda8b1f9da94eaf6ae8cd0f1061aed1ec448cb664",
    "0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4",
    "0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d",
    "0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71",
    "0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a",
]


# Initialize Web3 connection
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(NODE_URL))
if not web3.is_connected():
    raise Exception("Failed to connect to Ethereum node")

# Initialize balances dictionary
balances = {}


def wei_to_ether(wei_value):
    """Convert Wei to Ether."""
    return wei_value / 10**18


def update_balances(from_address, to_address, amount):
    """Update balances based on a transaction."""
    balances[from_address] = balances.get(from_address, 0) - amount
    balances[to_address] = balances.get(to_address, 0) + amount


def trace_transaction(tx_hash):
    """Use trace_transaction to get detailed transaction info."""
    try:
        traces = web3.provider.make_request("trace_transaction", [tx_hash])
        return traces["result"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error tracing transaction {tx_hash}: {e}")
        return None


def process_trace(trace_data, tx_hash):
    """Process trace data to update balances."""
    for trace in trace_data:
        action = trace.get("action", {})
        from_address = action.get("from")
        to_address = action.get("to")
        value = int(action.get("value", "0x0"), 16)  # Convert hex value to integer

        # Enhanced debugging information
        print(
            f"TxHash: {tx_hash}, Trace: from {from_address} to {to_address}, value {value}."
        )

        if value > 0 and from_address and to_address:
            update_balances(from_address, to_address, value)

        # Further logic for gas fees and other special cases


def main():
    for tx_hash in TX_HASHES:
        trace_data = trace_transaction(tx_hash)
        if trace_data:
            process_trace(trace_data, tx_hash)

    # Convert Wei balances to Ether and print
    balances_in_ether = {
        addr: wei_to_ether(balance) for addr, balance in balances.items()
    }
    print(json.dumps(balances_in_ether, indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what it does and its logic:

##### Script Workflow

1. **Iterating Over Transactions**:

   - The script iterates over each transaction hash in the `TX_HASHES` list.
   - For each transaction hash, it requests the Ethereum node for trace data.
2. **Processing Transaction Traces**:

   - Each transaction's trace data is processed to understand the flow of Ether.
   - This involves identifying the sender (`from`) and receiver (`to`) addresses and the value transferred in each transaction component.
3. **Updating Balances**:

   - Based on the extracted data, the script updates the `balances` dictionary to reflect the changes in Ether balances for each address involved.
4. **Debugging Information**:

   - The script prints out details for each trace, including transaction hash, sender, receiver, and value. This helps in debugging and verifying the script's functionality.
5. **Final Output**:

   - After processing all transactions, the script converts the balance changes from Wei to Ether.
   - It then prints the final balance changes in a human-readable format (Ether).

> Please note that this is a proof of concept, and it will require more testing to ensure accuracy. But it's a good start on how to approach such a big task.

The output will look like this:

```sh
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0x4eb8769a89b91b60a14ad1d30f2b136d9cf61b18 to 0xcb83ca9633ad057bd88a48a5b6e8108d97ad4472, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0xcb83ca9633ad057bd88a48a5b6e8108d97ad4472 to 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0xcb83ca9633ad057bd88a48a5b6e8108d97ad4472 to 0x188e817b02e635d482ae4d81e25dda98a97c4a42, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0xcb83ca9633ad057bd88a48a5b6e8108d97ad4472 to 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0x188e817b02e635d482ae4d81e25dda98a97c4a42, value 0.
TxHash: 0x7d19e5aed44365b7054290f0bccf7f88efa0919a89df2070e2f816199e6a3461, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0xd9c4434a5294bd82979c73f52d239bb2930f7429 to 0x6719c6ebf80d6499ca9ce170cda72beb3f1d1a54, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0x6719c6ebf80d6499ca9ce170cda72beb3f1d1a54 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0x6719c6ebf80d6499ca9ce170cda72beb3f1d1a54 to 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0x188e817b02e635d482ae4d81e25dda98a97c4a42, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0x188e817b02e635d482ae4d81e25dda98a97c4a42, value 0.
TxHash: 0x54342c2d2327e2872bf770567ac8a01afc9af57cc4ecfe86e3cfe006adee5028, Trace: from 0x2b68ead18db86cd6130df53c4b6c3c77332a3351 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0xf5213a6a2f0890321712520b8048d9886c1a9900 to 0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564 to 0x465e56cd21ad47d4d4790f17de5e0458f20c3719, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0x465e56cd21ad47d4d4790f17de5e0458f20c3719 to 0xd1d2eb1b1e90b638588728b4130137d262c87cae, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0xd1d2eb1b1e90b638588728b4130137d262c87cae to 0x8d92a6812b3da2346883f0631910c96cb9c5a5f9, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0x465e56cd21ad47d4d4790f17de5e0458f20c3719 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0x465e56cd21ad47d4d4790f17de5e0458f20c3719 to 0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xfe5372220da4e2ce2d7d3976d41fbdf4d0d5909aee96135a6fbfeca79b385cf8, Trace: from 0x465e56cd21ad47d4d4790f17de5e0458f20c3719 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x8c7dd9f6c3aec7e3e49cbf95eb602ff356929de72179515b5cc0270b64d83a32, Trace: from 0x3bb536776f0ce9dcbf486ef2da6166c4c480b985 to 0xbc55cb1217b214e8bfd17449ba371cd1fddf5f7a, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0xa4606dfaedc482670ef4567187645b4052e189ab to 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e, value 200000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x6599ae06914f1f5ec0053d3f475348d40e608442, value 200000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 200000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xcc6773f710b7f2a2357e228609c114f8fae04b61, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc0920dbec5d5c6fe9b7a9709277decbb37bb6716, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc0920dbec5d5c6fe9b7a9709277decbb37bb6716, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0xc0920dbec5d5c6fe9b7a9709277decbb37bb6716 to 0xcc6773f710b7f2a2357e228609c114f8fae04b61, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0xc0920dbec5d5c6fe9b7a9709277decbb37bb6716 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0xc0920dbec5d5c6fe9b7a9709277decbb37bb6716 to 0xcc6773f710b7f2a2357e228609c114f8fae04b61, value 0.
TxHash: 0xcbe55b42c1e9dfb7eb807496edd06e5f38d64548a9c29e653f2e523016d67a1e, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xcc6773f710b7f2a2357e228609c114f8fae04b61, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0x77ad3a15b78101883af36ad4a875e17c86ac65d1 to 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8, value 234926567.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8 to 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd2d6aec5f02ef4875c069628d6826a111249040cd9652c5071a65dc6ab87841c, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0xd92798abca9b68a122ffd7363541a19bee517786 to 0x881d40237659c251811cec9c364ef91dc08d300c, value 950000000000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x881d40237659c251811cec9c364ef91dc08d300c to 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631, value 950000000000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631 to 0x7cdf68ce9a05413cbb76cb7f80eaf415a826e313, value 950000000000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631 to 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582, value 941687500000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 941687500000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582 to 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582 to 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631 to 0xf326e4de8f66a0bdc0970b79e0924e33c79f1915, value 8312500000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0xf326e4de8f66a0bdc0970b79e0924e33c79f1915 to 0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552, value 8312500000000000.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631 to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x119f88f59d0e726c9fa733ff7e909982d65e10c99caa5f4848df4e4c1253be56, Trace: from 0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631 to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0x77ad3a15b78101883af36ad4a875e17c86ac65d1 to 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8, value 237933011.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8 to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8 to 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f, value 0.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0x4c45bbec2ff7810ef4a77ad7bd4757c446fe4155, value 0.
TxHash: 0x6ee6328db61a897928ecbbb3b179d06dead335669ca67e60e89793103bc27b13, Trace: from 0xcd02a882804f3eb0f2d80f94a04defcea038359f to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x004903819dbb2ce40e3eaf6bda8b1f9da94eaf6ae8cd0f1061aed1ec448cb664, Trace: from 0xd4b1d3df01d518247ebacfa116b9ccc295d37f65 to 0xcc6773f710b7f2a2357e228609c114f8fae04b61, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x1d9262af4e61af885ef60ab76e35454b02b82a50 to 0x6f1cdbbb4d53d226cf4b917bf768b94acbab6168, value 12536.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x6f1cdbbb4d53d226cf4b917bf768b94acbab6168 to 0x12cc685eeb95d3fcdfae0a996e214e51fa6f7548, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x12cc685eeb95d3fcdfae0a996e214e51fa6f7548 to 0x00c83aecc790e8a4453e5dd3b0b4b3680501a7a7, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x00c83aecc790e8a4453e5dd3b0b4b3680501a7a7 to 0x1820a4b7618bde71dce8cdc73aab6c95905fad24, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x00c83aecc790e8a4453e5dd3b0b4b3680501a7a7 to 0xc04a10fd5e6513242558f47331568abd6185a310, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0xc04a10fd5e6513242558f47331568abd6185a310 to 0x538d2b8cc2335c9495a6bfc9a57eb8e9c389d5f1, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x00c83aecc790e8a4453e5dd3b0b4b3680501a7a7 to 0x4ee5f270572285776814e32952446e9b7ee15c86, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x4ee5f270572285776814e32952446e9b7ee15c86 to 0x2db9ccb342003421544faba8cdf670ab922de5d3, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x4ee5f270572285776814e32952446e9b7ee15c86 to 0x06dd71dab27c1a3e0b172d53735f00bf1a66eb79, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x06dd71dab27c1a3e0b172d53735f00bf1a66eb79 to 0xd214df04c80569d6207c687f083b3c51dc7dd717, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x00c83aecc790e8a4453e5dd3b0b4b3680501a7a7 to 0x1820a4b7618bde71dce8cdc73aab6c95905fad24, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x12cc685eeb95d3fcdfae0a996e214e51fa6f7548 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x12cc685eeb95d3fcdfae0a996e214e51fa6f7548 to 0x6f1cdbbb4d53d226cf4b917bf768b94acbab6168, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x6f1cdbbb4d53d226cf4b917bf768b94acbab6168 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xd1d0f89ee9c42b5eb55a5125b67f135ef404e934e8c2e585c82a6671fa73cce4, Trace: from 0x12cc685eeb95d3fcdfae0a996e214e51fa6f7548 to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x1529282ea2d39c1a7a78608c0d0cab72a265196d to 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e, value 50000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x6599ae06914f1f5ec0053d3f475348d40e608442, value 50000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 50000000000000000.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x883f5df5f8785d9c54b927b1362332b06b69bb56, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x95e3d0fb07a33737e02fcfa0b14575f778e3391f, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x95e3d0fb07a33737e02fcfa0b14575f778e3391f, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x95e3d0fb07a33737e02fcfa0b14575f778e3391f to 0x883f5df5f8785d9c54b927b1362332b06b69bb56, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x95e3d0fb07a33737e02fcfa0b14575f778e3391f to 0x883f5df5f8785d9c54b927b1362332b06b69bb56, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x95e3d0fb07a33737e02fcfa0b14575f778e3391f to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0xb055f43cd396985f8514607936921b314ae726ec2052791fffec656bcf8cb69d, Trace: from 0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e to 0x883f5df5f8785d9c54b927b1362332b06b69bb56, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x1b5bbc00d336e42ce6dd79dda4b5ab056a614f4b to 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad, value 500000000000000000.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 500000000000000000.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0x67f4c72a50f8df6487720261e188f2abe83f57d7, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0xa7fd8ff8f4cada298286d3006ee8f9c11e2ff84e, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0xa7fd8ff8f4cada298286d3006ee8f9c11e2ff84e, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0xa7fd8ff8f4cada298286d3006ee8f9c11e2ff84e to 0x67f4c72a50f8df6487720261e188f2abe83f57d7, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0xa7fd8ff8f4cada298286d3006ee8f9c11e2ff84e to 0x67f4c72a50f8df6487720261e188f2abe83f57d7, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0xa7fd8ff8f4cada298286d3006ee8f9c11e2ff84e to 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, value 0.
TxHash: 0x21fb0d311272b3182c4a486a5226aedccdfea57af8818d67a57e9c28ee4b0d71, Trace: from 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad to 0x67f4c72a50f8df6487720261e188f2abe83f57d7, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0xfa69c0f63545562d6749b449f11c074a3d99a378 to 0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d to 0x4f9fc4e0b79c1cbf16e68863ad5e9de6a94a346c, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d to 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d to 0x4f9fc4e0b79c1cbf16e68863ad5e9de6a94a346c, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x4f9fc4e0b79c1cbf16e68863ad5e9de6a94a346c to 0x9ff58067bd8d239000010c154c6983a325df138e, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x9ff58067bd8d239000010c154c6983a325df138e to 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5 to 0x668c1dae7b4e5e865b45b0111acc71f0dddede8a, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5 to 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5 to 0x668c1dae7b4e5e865b45b0111acc71f0dddede8a, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x3e78f37b3902be9e0b3d370339294489023dc1f5 to 0xfa69c0f63545562d6749b449f11c074a3d99a378, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x4f9fc4e0b79c1cbf16e68863ad5e9de6a94a346c to 0x9ff58067bd8d239000010c154c6983a325df138e, value 0.
TxHash: 0x828d35754b69f4a5f6abcd45408ecf86733bf436e94cfc006fa4047747a9be0a, Trace: from 0x4f9fc4e0b79c1cbf16e68863ad5e9de6a94a346c to 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7, value 0.
{
    "0xa4606dfaedc482670ef4567187645b4052e189ab": -0.2,
    "0x80a64c6d7f12c47b7c66c5b4e20e72bc1fcd5d9e": -0.25,
    "0x6599ae06914f1f5ec0053d3f475348d40e608442": 0.25,
    "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2": 1.6916875,
    "0x77ad3a15b78101883af36ad4a875e17c86ac65d1": -4.72859578e-10,
    "0x00000000a991c429ee2ec6df19d40fe0c80088b8": 4.72859578e-10,
    "0xd92798abca9b68a122ffd7363541a19bee517786": -0.95,
    "0x881d40237659c251811cec9c364ef91dc08d300c": 0.0,
    "0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631": -0.95,
    "0x7cdf68ce9a05413cbb76cb7f80eaf415a826e313": 0.95,
    "0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582": 0.0,
    "0xf326e4de8f66a0bdc0970b79e0924e33c79f1915": 0.0,
    "0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552": 0.0083125,
    "0x1d9262af4e61af885ef60ab76e35454b02b82a50": -1.2536e-14,
    "0x6f1cdbbb4d53d226cf4b917bf768b94acbab6168": 1.2536e-14,
    "0x1529282ea2d39c1a7a78608c0d0cab72a265196d": -0.05,
    "0x1b5bbc00d336e42ce6dd79dda4b5ab056a614f4b": -0.5,
    "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad": 0.0
}
```

On the docs, you can learn more about [trace_transaction](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-trace_transaction).

As you can see, it will display the change of ETH for each address. Notice that some values are so small that are not displayed correctly; you'll need to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

I use debug_traceBlockByNumber and specify callTracer as the tracer, so I get every internal call of the block. And track values of these calls

Also you can trace separate transactions same way

P.S. tracing whole blocks is faster than every transaction